# mod rewrite to IIS rewrite rule issue

Tags: .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, web-config

Hi im getting these errors when im trying to to convert this file in IIS mod_rewrite

> This directive was not converted because it is not supported by IIS:
>   RewriteBase /php-login/

And

> The condition pattern is not supported: -l

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /php-login/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here it is in XML view with the errors please have a look at the errors

```
<rewrite>
<!--This directive was not converted because it is not supported by IIS: RewriteBase /php-login/.-->
<rules>
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<!--The condition pattern is not supported: -l.-->
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: So the features in question are probably not supported by IIS and you either have to do without them or figure out how to replace them with whatever is supported. You may want to reformulate your question accordingly.

Comment: I have no clue to make it work is there a way because i really need that or do you have any other solution that has the same function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> So the features in question are probably not supported by IIS and you
>   either have to do without them or figure out how to replace them with
>   whatever is supported. You may want to reformulate your question
>   accordingly. –  SVD Mar 19 at 22:17